# Can run 3D games but not Unity(only 2D version). GeForce 8800 GTS 12.04

Tags: nvidia, compiz, 12.04, freeze, unity-2d

I'm having trouble getting Unity to run properly. I can play HoN but if I log in with Unity the system becomes slow and laggy.I think this system had earlier versions of Unity running before but now it does not. One day in version 11.04 it started freezing so I upgraded to 12.04 to see if the issue would disappear by itself but it didn't.

I'm using the drivers included in Additional Drivers, "NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver(version current) [Recommended]".

I also got this error message when I logged in with Unity 2D that Window Decoration has stopped working or something. It also said something about Compiz.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using 64bit edition from Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. I'm using a Nvidia GeForce 8800 GTS and it worked perfectly in earlier versions of Ubuntu. The system was running on 11.04 (32Bit edition) as unity began to be extremly slow and unusable directly after startup, so I upgraded to 12.04 but still have the same issue. Unity 2D is still working, altough it crashes some times.
I'm using the same additional driver as LeMisanthrope. I think the problem has something to do with compiz, as soon as I kill compiz, the system "works".

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need disable flipping in OpenGl Settings:

[image: Settings screen]

Comment: Sorry for long delay, Unity 2D worked so well that I forgot about this problem.

Disabling Flipping does the trick. I am now logged in to regular Unity although I don't notice any difference.